# chart js how do I only show just the low/high dots on line chart?

Tags: chart.js, linechart

How do i only show data points for the low and high?  Every other data point can be hovered over to get their value but by default just the low and high should always show with custom tooltip

[image: low high chart]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution in case this helps anyone else out.

1. as i generate my xData and yData from api, i then grab min/max value from array
2. then i loop thru yData array and pull out the index of the min/max
3. as i'm initializing line chart, i used a function for pointRadius in the datasets that sets the dot to 10 if it's low or high, if not set it to 0 so it doesn't show

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]